# Is there any way to use Koin inject with generic?

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I heve base class and I would like to use Koin injection on this base class like:

```
abstract class BasePresenterFragment<T : BasePresenter> : BaseFragment() {

    lateinit var presenter: T by inject<T>() // here is problem

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        presenter.subscribe()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        presenter.unSubscribe()
    }
}
```

I know there are solutions for inject viewModel but not for simple injection. So is there any way to use Koin injection with generic type?

Comment: Why not `abstract val presenter: T` and `override val presenter: ConcretePresenter by inject()`? Or does that not work?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes for now I've found only this way. But this only partly solve my case. Because I still need write inject() line for every subclass of BasePresenterFragment like:
override val presenter: SomePresenter by inject ()
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I've found only partly solution for this question. It's use presenter like abstract val in base class. This will make it possible to use the methods of presenter in the base class but I still should use `inject()` in every subclasses for initialization. Example:

```
abstract class BasePresenterFragment<P : BasePresenter> : BaseFragment() {

    abstract val presenter: P

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        presenter.subscribe()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        presenter.unSubscribe()
    }
}
```

And subclass:

```
class HomeFragment : BasePresenterFragment<HomeContract.Presenter>(), HomeContract.View {
     ...
     override val presenter: HomeContract.Presenter by inject()
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Koin does not support generics by default.

"Koin definitions doesn't take in accounts generics type argument."

however you are supposed to you the named argument to workaround this:

The latest Version even supports directly passing the type insted of a custom string:

```
module {
  single(named<Int>) { ArrayList<Int>() }
  single(named<String>) { ArrayList<String>() }
}
```

and when injecting, simply use `get(named<Int>)` or `get(named<String>)` depending on your need. For more information cf.: https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/definitions/

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is **Yes**

if you have generic classes like this :

the interface :

```
interface UseCase<Input, Output> {
    suspend operator fun invoke(input: Input): Output
}
```

class implement interface :

```
class UpdateMovieUseCase internal constructor(
    private val repository: MovieRepository
) : UseCase<MovieDomainModel, Unit> {
    override suspend fun invoke(movie: MovieDomainModel) =
        repository.update(movie.toData())
}
```

then you can provide a module in **KOIN** like this :

```
val domainModule = module {
    singleOf(::UpdateMovieUseCase) { bind<UseCase<MovieDomainModel, Unit>>() }
}
```

source code : https://github.com/Adnan9011/movie_archive